# In firefox form is not getting submitted after adding onsubmit attribute to form

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, onsubmit

I have a simple form like below.

```
<form onsubmit="return showProgressBar();" method="post" action="charts?operation=dashboard" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
<button type="submit">Upload</button>

</form>
```

and two js methods like below

```
<script>
    function showProgressBar(){
        return displayProgressBar();
    }

    function displayProgressBar(){
        var imgUrl = commonObj.appBasePath + '/static/images/ajax-loader.gif';
        $("#content").html('<div align="center" style="padding-top:200px"><img src="' +  imgUrl+'" /></div>');
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

With this in Firefox, the form is not being submitted. This works properly in chrome.

If I remove the onsubmit attribute then it works in firefox too.

What is the issue here in firefox?

If I remove method call and directly return true then it works as below.

```
function showProgressBar(){
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Where have you placed your JavaScript code, in header or in body?

Comment: I have put it in the body.

Comment: Ok, it must be ABOVE the form.

Comment: It is above the form only.

Comment: Does the firefox debug Tool show any errors?

Comment: No errors at all. If i directly return true then it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are replacing your `form` with progress bar. Isn't it in the `div` with `id=content`?

I was able to reproduce it, please check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLhmd7nw/4/

In Chrome you will get error response from jsfiddle site, while in firefox text 'progress bar' will appear and when you look at network requests there isn't one with form submission.